# DNS set up by using yahoo small business

Tags: web, dns

I'm trying to deploy my website and bind dns to this website. So, the dns was used by the old website and now I need to access the dns setting page and modify its A Record and pair its domain name to its new ip address. The domain name is managed by yahoo small business. So I log in and done the changeup like this.
[image]

however, When I type the "vbridgetech.com" it does show the apache default page. But when I type "www.vbridgetech.com" it still goes to the old webpage. I thought the only thing I have to do is to change the old ip to new ip. Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 59.120.185.12 is you new site's IP address, then just add another `CNAME` record:

```
CNAME record    www.vbridgetech.com    vbridgetech.com
```

(There are other ways to do this, but this should be the safe one)